# Composer autoload file not working

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

My Autoload specification are as follows

```
  "autoload" : {
        "psr-4" : {
            "MyMVC\\" : "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "app/Controllers",
            "app/Helpers"
        ],
        "files": ["app/routes.php"]
    },
```

The contents of routes.php file are:

```
<?php
use MyMVC\Core\Route;

$route = new Route;
$route->add('/', 'HomeController@index');
$route->add('about', 'AboutController@index');
$route->add('contact', 'ContactController@index');
```

now in my `app/init.php` i am trying to use the `$route` object but its giving me error

```
Notice: Undefined variable: route in /var/www/html/mymvc/app/init.php on line 29
```

Here is how i am trying to use the `$route` object.

```
/**
 * Constructor
 * Bootstrap our application based on the configurations provided
 */
public function __construct()
{
    // require 'app/routes.php` This will work fine but it should be autoloaded
    var_dump($route);
    exit;
}
```

I have also ran command `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Variable scope: http://php.net/manual/it/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: oh man :O silly me ! Thank you so much

Comment: @Leggendario It is still not working. I tried to var dump at the start of the file outside of construction and even outside of class.

Comment: Have you included the autoloader?

Comment: yes autloader is included in `index.php` and this `app/init.php` is also included in `index.php`

Comment: Please include your `index.php` and `app/init.php` files

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek you mean in question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autoloading won't work here. PHP can only autoload classes. Your expectation that `app/routes.php` will be autoloaded is not possible, because that file does not contain a class declaration, and you are not able to trigger it's execution by using a previously unknown class.

It is true that Composer will execute that file once when you include `vendor/autoload.php` - however, this is really bad behavior of your software. Don't use the "files" autoloading to include configuration files. Mind the performance impact this may have when being used in libraries. You should avoid using it altogether, it is meant to be used for legacy code that cannot otherwise be made working.

On the other hand, your architecture is broken. You shouldn't write a class that "magically" knows about the configuration just by accessing a variable that is supposed to be initialized somewhere else. A good pattern would be to pass the configuration as a parameter to the constructor:

```
public function __construct ($routes)
{
    $this->routes = $routes;
}
```

The part of the code that creates this class is supposed to grab the configuration from somewhere and pass it as a parameter. This concept is called inversion of control or dependency injection: Classes do not invoke the other classes they need to work with, they ask for them and get them as a parameter.